# Notification if shell script runs long

Tags: linux, shell

I have a single shell script that runs a series of commands to query and extract files, let's call this script *EXTRACT.sh*. I want to send a notification (email) to myself that will monitor this script to notify me if this script runs longer than say an hour and continue running. How should I go about doing this?

I'm thinking I could write another script that loops the main script (EXTRACT.sh), but I'm wondering if there is any way to wrap all my current code in EXTRACT.sh to perform the same function of measuring run-time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like this in bash:

```
function do_the_job() {
   sleep 10
   # stands for the long task
}
#spawn the job in background
do_the_job&

# check every 3 seconds if the job is still running
while [ "$(jobs -r)x" != "x" ]
do
   sleep 3
   echo too long: sending email
done
```

Comment: Hi @OznOg, can you elaborate more on $(jobs -r)x? Is "x" supposed to the max amount of time? Thanks.

Comment: no, the "job" stuff is just to check if the do_the_job is still running. The timeout is the sleep 3.

Answer (score -1):

You can install a sleepy background job, that you will kill on exit.

Saving the following as `test.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

notification() {
        echo notification!      
}
( sleep 5; trap - EXIT; notification ) &
trap "kill $! 2>/dev/null ||:" EXIT

echo Working.....
sleep $1
echo Done working!
```

On fast job the background gets killed:

```
$ bash -x ./test.sh 4
+ trap 'kill 10960 2>/dev/null ||:' EXIT
+ echo Working.....
Working.....
+ sleep 4
+ sleep 5
+ echo Done 'working!'
Done working!
+ kill 10960
```

But when the job takes more then 5 seconds, the notification comes:

```
$ bash -x ./test.sh 6
+ trap 'kill 11088 2>/dev/null ||:' EXIT
+ echo Working.....
Working.....
+ sleep 6
+ sleep 5
+ trap - EXIT
+ notification
+ echo 'notification!'
notification!
+ echo Done 'working!'
Done working!
+ kill 11088
+ :
```